# Using fog with three.js Meshline Add-on

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hey im using Three meshline an add-on for three js you can find here.
https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine/tree/master/src.
it works great in my code the only thing is, fog does not apply on its special own material new MeshLineMaterial. Is there any way to implement the fog value to the meshline.js file?

Thanks for your help

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    for( var k = 0; k < splinePoints.length; k++) {
        var v = new THREE.Vector3( splinePoints[k].x + 3* Math.sin(k/4), splinePoints[k].y + 3 *Math.cos(k/4),  splinePoints[k].z);
        geometry.vertices.push( v );
    }    
makeLine(geometry, Colors.red);

function makeLine( geo, c ) {
var g = new MeshLine();
g.setGeometry( geo );

var material = new MeshLineMaterial( {
    color: new THREE.Color( c ),
    opacity: 1,
    lineWidth: 1
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( g.geometry, material );
graph.add( mesh );
}
```

Comment: show your code here.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: For now you have two options: see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11040, or, use your version and add the [fog code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk) into the shader.

Comment: could you explain me how to exactly "add" the fog code into the shader? im new to three and don't really know how the shaders work and where to begin adding the code.

Comment: nobody? I've tried several times but it always occurs errors